# Given $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 1$, prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2a_n-1}{n^2+a_n^2}=1$?

Tags: limits

Given $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 1$, how can I prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^2a_n-1}{n^2+a_n^2}=1$? I was trying to solve it by the epsilon definition of limit but didn't figure out how...

Comment: Multiply the numerator and denominator by $1/n^{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

$\lim_{n \to \infty}{(n^{2}a_n-1)\over(n^2+(a_n)^2)}=\lim_{n \to \infty}{({1\over a_n}-{1\over n^2{a_n}^2})\over({1\over{a_n}^2}+{1\over n^2})}={1-0\over 1+0}=1$

Comment: Ahh I got you! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $n \geq 1$, then
$$
\bigg| \frac{n^{2}a_{n}-1}{n^{2}+a_{n}^{2}} - 1 \bigg|
=
\bigg| \frac{n^{2}a_{n}-1-n^{2}-a_{n}^{2}}{n^{2}+a_{n}^{2}} \bigg|
\leq
\frac{n^{2}|a_{n}-1|}{n^{2}+a_{n}^{2}} + \frac{a^{2}_{n}+1}{n^{2}+a_{n}^{2}}
\leq
|a_{n}-1| + \frac{a^{2}_{n}+1}{n^{2}}.
$$
Let $\varepsilon > 0$; then by assumption there are some $N_{1},N_{2} \geq 1$ such that for all $n \geq N_{1}$ we have $|a_{n}-1| < \varepsilon/2$ and for all $n \geq N_{2}$ we have $\frac{a^{2}_{n}+1}{n^{2}} < \varepsilon/2;$ so if $n \geq \max\{N_{1}, N_{2} \}$, then we can make the absolute difference $< \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see it is to do the partial fractions
$$
\frac{n^2a_n-1}{n^2+a_n^2}=a_n-\frac{a_n^3+1}{n^2+a_n^2}
$$